# how can i use binary search in c# for generic list

Tags: c#, sorting, binary-search

I would like to sort my list and then use a binary search to find a name in the list and display it.

```cs
public abstract class animal {
  protected int age
  protected string name
  public print() {
    console.writeline({
      age
    } + {
     name
    });
  }
  animal() {}~animal() {}
}

public class pets {
  private List<animal> list = new List<animal>();

  public void search(string m) {
    int index = list.BinarySearch(m);
    if (index == 0)
      list[index].print();
  }
}
```

Comment: Please post your actual code next time. What you've posted won't compile.

Comment: sorry for that , im stressed and i don't have much time

Comment: What is `animal() {}~animal() {}`? I made an effort to cleanup the code but couldn’t make sense of that. Also, did you mean to use string interpolation in `Console.WriteLine()`, I assume?

Comment: @Hunter: I understand your stressed and don’t have much time. We’ve all been there! But taking a moment more to put care into your question will help ensure you get a useful answer faster—and ultimately save you time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The built-in `BinarySearch` method does not let you pass in a value of a type other than the type of the list. To use the built-in [`BinarySearch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.binarysearch?view=netcore-3.1#System_Collections_Generic_List_1_BinarySearch__0_System_Collections_Generic_IComparer__0__) you will need to either define a class that implements  `IComparer<Animal>` that compares by `Name`, or make `Animal` implement `IComparable<Animal>` so that two animals are compared by name by default. Then you `Sort()` the list and call `BinarySearch`, passing an `Animal` instance that has the name you want to search for.

You'd have to implement your own `BinarySearch` method to search for an object with a given property value (assuming, of course, that the list is sorted by that same property).

If you just want to use regular linear search methods to search for an animal with a given name, you can use a straight `foreach` loop, `break`ing when the item with that name is found, or use the `First()` Linq method (which basically does the same thing).